# jquery scrolling after inserting object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, scroll

I have a rails app and using bootstrap. After updating and and reinserting an object I'd like to scroll to the top of the div with a quick animation since I'm ordering based on updated_at. I tried different versions but couldn't make it happen properly. All I achieved was to be able to scroll to the top of the window with no animation.

How can I make it work?

```
<body>
  <header>.....</header>
  <div id ="sidebar">...</div>       //this is not scrollable
  <div id = "page-content-wrapper">  //I can't decide which one is the scrollable one(wrapper/container/post-index)
    <div class="container-fluid post-container">
      <div class="post-index new-post-insert">
        <%= render @posts %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

create.js.erb (this gets invoked when object is updated)

```
$('#post_<%= @post.id %>').remove(); //old object gets removed
$(".new-post-insert").prepend($post); //new object get inserted to the top

//THIS ONE IS WORKING, BUT NOT IDEAL
window.scrollTo(0,0);

//I ALSO TRIED THESE WITH DIFFERENT CLASSES (wrapper/container/post-index) BUT NON OF THESE WERE WORKING
//window.animate({ scrollTo(0,window.offset().top) }, 1000);
//$('.post-container').scrollTop(100);
//$('#page-content-wrapper').scrollTo(0, $('#post_<%= @post.id %>').offset().top);
//$('.new-post-insert').stop().animate({scrollTop: $post.offset().top}, '500');
//$('#page-content-wrapper').scrollTop($('.post-index')[0].scrollHeight);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this if you want a smooth animation

```
 $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
```